# How do I know if my GPU has been properly configured on Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, graphics, gpu

I recently began experimenting with some "older" mainstream games utilizing GUI's e.g. Old School Runescape, Runescape, Minecraft, Roblox, some games on Steam such as Baldur's Gate, etc. I do notice a difference in performance compared to when my laptop computer had Windows XP, Windows Vista and Windows 7 installed on it, and, know that the hardware is capable of running the aforementioned games on higher graphics/video settings. I understand that there are ways to manipulate or update the Ubuntu environment as to sort of switch from the default/generic/on-board GPU to the "more powerful" GPU, but cannot seem to find the exact solution. After many searches and much research I decided I'd come here and ask if there's anything that I can do regarding utilizing the "better" GPU on my computer by default - mostly just to access the GPU's RAM when experimenting with games, video, graphics, etc.

How can I make sure that the GPU is properly updated and configured on Ubuntu? (firmware, drivers, etc.) And how do I know if the GPU that I want to use is the default GPU in Ubuntu?

Is it just a simple matter of switching from the motherboard to the GPU when calling the hardware to be used when utilizing applications with video?

The short is the following:

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

description:    Notebook
product:    Aspire 7750G
vendor: Acer
version:    V1.14
serial: LXRCZ022601422634E1601
width:  64 bits
capabilities:   smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
configuration:
boot    =   normal
chassis =   notebook
uuid    =   551EFE49-FA23-11E0-A843-DC0EA10D7242

Please let me know if you can help out at all and if you need any additional information.. thanks in advance!

Comment: "Aspire 7750G" doesn't say much useful. The model number has been sold over a period of years with different Intel CPUs and different AMD graphics. That said one or the other have full support with open-source native drivers (kernel modules). It's recommended to use a lighter flavor like Lubuntu or Xubuntu but even that won't make much difference. You can't compare the requirements of 20 years old OSes with anything currently supported.

Comment: In a nutshell, the previous comment implies that there's nothing you can do to "improve" performance form the point of the OS, drivers or software. Some improvement can happen by maxing out the RAM and replacing the old HDD with a 2.5" SSD.

Comment: Thanks. Ya'll are great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.